# Find the characteristic of $Z_n \times Z_m$:

Tags: abstract-algebra

so I was given the problem: find the characteristic of $Z_3\times Z_4$  and I got 
$\operatorname{char}(Z_3\times Z_4)=12$, is it true that for any $Z_n \times Z_m$, 
$\operatorname{char}(Z_n \times Z_m)=n*m$???

so for instance, does $\operatorname{char}(Z_2\times Z_3)=6$?

For $\operatorname{char}(Z_{10}\times Z_{20})$ would you take 20*10, or 10 because thats the GCF, or 2 because thats the lowest common factor????

Thanks!

Comment: A tip: When you hover your mouse on top of a tag, you get a brief description of what it means. Doing that here and reading it would reveal that [tag: characteristic-function] is not appropriate for your question.

Comment: But have you tried applying the definition of characteristic? What problems did you encounter while doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** I'd say $char(\mathbb{Z}_m\times \mathbb{Z}_n)=lcm(m,n)$. Can you see why?

> Note $\mathbb{Z}_m\times \mathbb{Z}_n$ is a ring with unity $(1,1)$, so if we can find the characteristic of $(1,1)$, then we are done.

Let $k$ be its characteristic.

Then, $k(1,1)=(0\pmod m,0\pmod n)$

$(k,k)=(0\pmod m,0\pmod n)$

$m|k$ and $n|k\Rightarrow lcm(m,n)|k$

It is fairly simple to show that $k|lcm(m,n)$

Comment: So for Z10*Z20 it would be 10?

Comment: $lcm(10,20)=20$

Comment: Sorry, I misread the beginning of the post... that makes sense!